# Command "currentOp" returned error "Invalid collection name specified 'admin.$cmd.sys.inprog'"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I just installed MongoDB Compass and connected to my DB. While watching the performance for around 10s I get the following error `Command "currentOp" returned error "Invalid collection name specified 'admin.$cmd.sys.inprog'"` and soon after that this one `Command "serverStatus" returned error "connection 19 to 127.0.0.1:29247 timed out"` Can anyone explain to me what this means and how to solve it?

Thanks